# type missmatch, java spring & hibernate, cannot convert data for mySQL database from Object to String

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Im cant fix bug in my app, error is becouse Im trying to add element Object type in database table in row which requie String type,what shall I do? :S
[problem is in getProductSave, something with Stickers.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "product-save")
public String getProductSave(@ModelAttribute Product product) {
    
    Category category = categoryService.getCategoryById(product.getCategory().getId());
    List<Sticker> stickers = new ArrayList<Sticker>();
    
    for(Sticker sticker : product.getStickers()) {
        
        Sticker tempSticker = stickerService.getStickerById(sticker.getId());
        
        stickers.add(tempSticker);
        
                
    }   
    product.setCategory(category);
    productDAO.saveProduct(product);
    product.setStickers(stickers);
    
    return "redirect: product-list";
    
}
```

Class Sticker has columns from table stickers in database

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column
private int id;
@Column
private String title;
@Column
private String color;
```

Class Product has field

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.REFRESH })
@JoinTable(name = "products_stickers", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="products_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="sticker_id"))
private List<Sticker> stickers;
```

Comment: Hi Nikola , can you please edit your question and add the code there don't add just the image, because someone who is trying to help you will need to copy the code and we can't copy from images :)

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. kindly try to explain the question on the main part itself. Please post the script/code along with the difficulty you face. read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a clear idea of how to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not adding the stickers to the product before saving it? This could be the problem. Please check relation between your intermediate table "product_stickers" and "product" table. Ultimately you wanted to add stickers to your product but missing it.

Comment: Thanks , changed, now is problem that hibernate doesnt save data in database table, is there any annotation for that?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any possibility that problem could be in Sticker class, in constructor or some annotation?

@Entity
@Table(name = "stickers")

public class Sticker {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column
private int id;
@Column
private String title;
@Column
private String color;

public Sticker() {
    
}

public Sticker(String title, String color) {
    
    this.title=title;
    this.color=color;
}
```